# Assistance with SQL Query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I heed your help with the following:

I have a table like this:

Table_Values

```
ID   |  Value | Date

1    |  ASD   | 01-Jan-2019

2    |  ZXC   | 10-Jan-2019

3    |  ASD   | 01-Jan-2019

4    |  QWE   | 05-Jan-2019

5    |  RTY   | 15-Jan-2019

6    |  QWE   | 29-Jan-2019
```

That I need is to get the values that are duplicated and have a different Date, for example the value "QWE" is duplicated and has different date:

```
ID   |  Value | Date

4    |  QWE   | 05-Jan-2019

6    |  QWE   | 29-Jan-2019
```

Answer (score 0):

With EXISTS:

```
select * from Table_Values t
where exists (
  select 1 from Table_Values
  where value = t.value and date <> t.date
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Join:**

```
select
   t1.* 
from
   Table_Values t1 
   join
      Table_Values t2 
      on t1.Value = t2.Value 
      and t1.Date <> t2.Date
```

However, Exists approach is better.

Answer (score 0):

You want all rows where there is more than one date per value. You can use `COUNT OVER` for this.

One method (featured as of Oracle 12c):

```
select id, value, date
from mytable
order by case when count(distinct date) over (partition by value) > 1 then 1 else 2 end
fetch first row with ties
```

But you'll have to put this into a subquery (derived table / cte), if you want the result sorted.

And another method without `FETCH FIRST` clause (valid as of Oracle 8i):

```
select id, value, date
from
(
  select id, value, date, count(distinct date) over (partition by value) as cnt
  from mytable
)
where cnt > 1
order by id, value, date;
```

forpas' solution with `EXISTS` may be faster, though. Well, pick whichever method you like better :-)

Answer (score 0):

With EXISTS, "correlated subquery" is used. So I don't think it's better than JOIN.
However, Oracle optimizer could re-write "EXISTS" to JOIN.

I like to use JOIN in classic way :)

```
SELECT t1.* 
  FROM table_values t1, table_values t2 
 WHERE t1.f_value =  t2.f_value 
   AND t1.f_date  <> t2.f_date 
 ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: EXISTS in this case is better than JOIN because it does not scan the whole table to find every possible match. It stops when it finds the 1st match.